# How to disable a Jcombobox item from a listener?

Tags: java, indexing, jcombobox

I have a problem with my project, since my goal is to let the user manually fill 6 fields with items in an array; I thought of 6 `JComboBox`es with the same items, when you select an item in one box, it becomes disabled in the rest. I'm starting, and although I've searched I only found the way to do it inside its constructor.

```
cb1.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){ 

@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
     if(cb1.getSelectedIndex()==1) {
         // this is as far as I go, but disables the entire jcombobox
         cb2.setEnabled(false);

         // this is more like I want, but it doesn't work.
         cb2.setSelectedIndex(1).setEnabled(false);                            
 }}});
```

If anyone knows a more efficient way to make possible to the user assign manually array items to many fields I would welcome it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way for you to disable the item of `JComboBox`. You can just remove it from the location here is how:-

```
import java.awt.Container;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JComboBox;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
public class Combobox extends JFrame{
Combobox(){
    this.setVisible(true);
    this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    String[] list={"car","bus","bike"};
    final JComboBox c1=new JComboBox(list);
    final JComboBox c2=new JComboBox(list);
    Container c=this.getContentPane();
    c.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
    c.add(c1);
    c.add(c2);
    c1.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            int index=c1.getSelectedIndex();
            c2.removeItemAt(index);
            }
    });
    this.pack();
}
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Combobox();
    }
}
```

`final JComboBox c1=new JComboBox(list);` will make a `JComboBox` have items of `list`. `final` is used since c1 is called inside inner class `ActionListener` which is used for clicking events. `index=c1.getSelectedIndex();` will get the `index location` of the selected item in `c1`. `c2.removeItemAt(index);` will remove the item which is at `index` location of c2. Since `c1` and `c2` both contains similar items so `index` position of items is same.
If you want to re-insert the item in c2 at some point then
save the index location of the item to be removed and the name of the item that is to be removed using

```
index=c1.getSelectedIndex();
item=c2.getItemAtIndex(index);
c2.removeItemAt(index);
```

then restore the items using

```
c2.insertItemAt(item,index);
```

**Note**- `index` and `item` should be declare outside  `ActionListener` if there are to be used outside it.

Comment: If this answer solved your problem the please click the tick mark to mark the question solved and mark the answer useful.

Comment: @EduardoSoriano if you liked the answer mark it useful and if it solved your problem mark question solved

Answer (score 0):

Try to enable ComboItem. Function setEnabled is used to for object, at your case cb2.